Why Is My Website Freezing After Clicking On An Item In The Menu? No Issue On A Mobile Device
While testing my website on a computer, whenever I click on an item in the menu bar on my website and go to that page, then go back to the previous page, for some reason the website freezes. If I refresh the frozen page, the website runs normally. I have no problems using the website on a mobile device.
I've tried looking to see if any of the CSS or Javascript in my website would be causing this issue, but I haven't found anything.
Below is the Javascript that I'm currently using on my website. I have it set so that the content behind the mobile menu doesn't move while open and so that it will close after an item in it has been clicked.
`document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
 if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
 document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }

}

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var closeHamp = function() {
 document.getElementsByClassName('cp_menuicon')[0].click();
    };

 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
 elements[i].addEventListener('click', closeHamp, false);
    }`

Could changing or removing this Javascript help sort out the issue? If anyone has any solutions, I’d appreciate it if you’d share them with me.
My Website

Check the browser's dev tools (or web inspector) to the Console tab for any potential JavaScript errors.

I'm not finding any errors related to the menu that might be causing issues. Any suggestions?

Not enough information to know, but keep the console open while navigating the pages to see if any errors occur. My guess is that some element class or id references are not present from one page to the next? ... so that the JavaScript events are not applied, which gives the frozen behavior.

Would setting this Javascript so that it only runs on a particular screen size help to solve this issue? I've been trying, but haven't been able to get the Javascript to recognize the screen size in which it should run. It ends up stopping the other code from running as it should be.
